# How to link a Referendum with a Treasury Proposal

Tags: treasury, opengov, referendum

I want to link the Open Gov referendum that requests funding from the Treasury with the Treasury proposal.

I see that this is done in Polkassembly. An example is this: The [Referenda](https://polkadot.polkassembly.io/referenda/62) which has an id 62 and the [Treasury Proposal](https://polkadot.polkassembly.io/treasury/355) which has an id 355.

If you see in the top they are linked, but checking the On-chain information I can't see how is actually linked

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the timeline page and open the executed link.

[image]

After the referenda were executed, there is an event indicating that the treasury proposal is 355.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution, is not 100% accurate you will be able to link it no? Because in the list of events of that block there is another event SpendApproved there is no link to your proposal